# Color only the points and let box plot black in ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how I could color only the points and let the geombox black in a ggboxplot?I want the inside to be white or empty and the lines of the box perimeter to remain black.

```
# Load data
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
# Change outline colors by groups: dose
# Use custom color palette
# Add jitter points and change the shape by groups
 ggboxplot(df, "dose", "len",
    color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
    add = "jitter", shape = "dose")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further clarification, it seems I understand what you are looking to do:

- plot the boxplot as a white box with the black lines
- add points to the plot, but make sure they do not obscure the box (the box should be "on top")

I think I have it right, correct?

If this is the case, then it's tough to do with `ggboxplot()` from `ggpubr`.  You'll need to control the plotting layers of `geom_jitter` (the points) and `geom_boxplot` (the boxplot) separately.  Just use `ggplot()` for that.  Additionally, since `df$dose` is continuous, it's probably best for you to turn that into a factor first to avoid having a continuous axis and continuous color scale (but that's more a preference).  I'll include that assumption in the answer, but if you remove the first line, you'll see the difference.

```
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)
ggplot(df, aes(dose, len)) + 
    geom_jitter(aes(color=dose), width=0.1) +
    geom_boxplot(fill='white', aes(group=dose))
```

[image]

Order matters here.  If you switch the ordering of `geom_boxplot` and `geom_jitter`, you'll get the points over top of the boxplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(dose, len)) +
    geom_boxplot(fill='white', aes(group=dose)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(color=dose), width=0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what "level" of blackness you want... let me explain.

**Color the boxes of the boxplot black:** Adjust the `fill=` aesthetic.

```
ggboxplot(df, "dose", "len",
          color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
          add = "jitter", shape = "dose", fill='black')
```

[image]

**Color everything black:**  There are some packages available, but really you can just create your own custom theme.

```
theme_inverted <- function() {
    theme_bw() %+replace%
        theme(
            plot.background = element_rect(fill='black'),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill='black'),
            text = element_text(color='white'),
            axis.text = element_text(color='white'),
            axis.line = element_line(color='white'),
            axis.ticks = element_line(color='white'),
            panel.grid = element_line(color='white'),
            legend.background = element_rect(fill='black'),
            legend.key = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA)
        )
}
```

Then you can just use that in `ggplot2` calls:

```
ggboxplot(df, "dose", "len",
          color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
          add = "jitter", shape = "dose", fill='black') +
    theme_inverted()
```

[image]

Comment: No I want the inside to be white or empty and the lines of the box perimeter to remain black

Comment: Oh, that was not too clear from your question.  Seems like you already have the answer from the others?  If not, please clarify in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the group and color aesthetics separately. I can't reproduce using `ggpubr` package but with `ggplot2` you can use this example:

```
require(ggplot2)
data("ToothGrowth")

# Define aesthetics separately for geom_boxplot and geom_point
ggplot(data = ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = dose)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(dose)), position = "jitter") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using your data just remove the `ggboxplot` arguments which control the points and substitute `ggplot::geom_point` and `scale_colour_manual` for what you need.

```r
# Load data

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth


ggboxplot(df, "dose", "len", 
          color = "black") +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = factor(dose), y = len, colour = factor(dose), shape = factor(dose)), position = position_jitter(width = 0.2))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>